# Can't see nearby Device while scanning in MultipeerConnectivity

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I am working to get **nearby Devices** using **MultipeerConnectivity framework**.
But When I scan for devices in simulator and hosted session in Real device. I can't see any device in `MCBrowserViewController`. Please help me Guys.

I am getting error when searching for Devices: `NSNetServiceBrowser did not search with error -72008 on iOS 14`

[image]

**Note:-**

1. Xcode version : 12.4
2. iOS device: 14.4.1
3. iOS Simulator 14.4

Code when User tap on Button:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
      let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Connect to others", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Host a session", style: .default) { alertAction in
            //here we will add a closure to host a session
            self.mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: self.peerID, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "hws-kb")
            //self.mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType:  "hws-kb", discoveryInfo: nil, session: self.mcSession)
            
            self.mcAdvertiserAssistant.delegate = self
            self.mcAdvertiserAssistant.startAdvertisingPeer()
    })
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Join a session", style: .default) { alertAction in
        //here we will add a closure to join a session
            self.browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "hws-kb", session: self.mcSession)
            self.browser.delegate = self
            self.present(self.browser, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
      ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
      present(ac, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: "But When I scan for devices in simulator and hosted session in Real device. I can't see any device in MCBrowserViewController."  Your simulator emits a signal?

Comment: I think so.. Yess

Comment: @Paulw11 But i have seen many Devs running on Simulator. Did you checked my question clearly.

Comment: Make sure that they are on the same network.

Comment: @ElTomato I have tried that as well